# SVG material shadow as background for cytoscape.js

Tags: svg, cytoscape.js

**Objective:**

1. I want to create SVG which can be used as background image , to mimic material drop shadow for [cytoscape](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image) library
2. SVG should be able to strech the given div, in my case cytoscape js node
3. My goal is to use it for [cytoscape](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image) library , i am not interested in css solutions for divs

**Issues:**
I have created SVG but I am not sure how to make it fit in node so that it fits nodes hegiht and width and produce material shadow effect.
**Maybe wrong view box ?**

**SVG Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/du25y4bc/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow-16dp" x="-50%" y="-100%" width="200%" height="300%">
      <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="offA" dy="16" />
      <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="offB" dy="6" />
      <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="offC" dy="8" />
      <feMorphology in="offA" result="spreadA" operator="dilate" radius="2" />
      <feMorphology in="offB" result="spreadB" operator="dilate" radius="5" />
      <feMorphology in="offC" result="spreadC" operator="erode" radius="5" />
      <feGaussianBlur in="spreadA" result="blurA" stdDeviation="12" />
      <!--24px 2px-->
      <feGaussianBlur in="spreadB" result="blurB" stdDeviation="15" />
      <!--30px 5px-->
      <feGaussianBlur in="spreadC" result="blurC" stdDeviation="5" />
      <!--10px -5px-->
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.14" result="opA" />
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.12" result="opB" />
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.40" result="opC" />
      <feComposite in="opA" in2="blurA" result="shA" operator="in" />
      <feComposite in="opB" in2="blurB" result="shB" operator="in" />
      <feComposite in="opC" in2="blurC" result="shC" operator="in" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="shA" />
        <feMergeNode in="shB" />
        <feMergeNode in="shC" />
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="45" y="54" fill="#FFFFFF" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#shadow-16dp)" />
</svg>
```